# I dont know why beautiful soup is nt scraping this webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I cant get beautiful soup to locate a certain element

I have tried changing the parser it uses and what its searching for

```
import urllib2
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url= driver.current_url

#sets the array counter
i = 1

#opens the url
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

#reads the url
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
print(soup)

h2 = soup.find_all("h3", {"class": "nbf_carparking_title nbf_tooltip"}) [i]

#sets strong value
strong = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "nbf_fancy_product_results_totalcost2"})[i]
#prints h2 (text)
print(h2).text
print(strong).text
```

I am expecting it to bring up the prices of certain products but instead it prints nothing

the url is https://www.weholiday.co.uk/travelreq.php?cd4504d8-b2a2-11e9-8114-3ca82a238f71

Comment: The URL points to error page.

Comment: Ah ok. is there any way to fix that using cookies?

Comment: Is the url of a webpage received after filling a form? if so, you can try filling the form using `MechanicalSoup` to receive the results you see on the browser, and work from there. notice that you should also use `print(h2.text)` instead of `print(h2).text`